# how to move file to error directory and rollback other move with apache camel?

Tags: apache-camel

First of all: i'm a camel newbie :-)

I want to transfer a file from an input directory to an output directory and do some java stuff.
If something goes wrong, i want to move the file to an error directory and rollback to move to the output directory.

This is my route in java dsl:

```
onException(Exception.class).handled(true).to("file://C:/temp/camel/error");
from("file://C:/temp/camel/in?delete=true").to("file://C:/temp/camel/out").bean(ServiceBean.class, "callWebservice");
```

If an error is thrown in the ServiceBean, the file is copied to the error folder, but it also stays in the out directory.

What is the best way to rollback?

Thanks

Answer (score 7):

There is a moveFailed option. Just use that, then you dont need the onException etc.
http://camel.apache.org/file2

```
from("file://C:/temp/camel/in?delete=true&moveFailed=C:/temp/camel/error")
  .to("file://C:/temp/camel/out")
  .bean(ServiceBean.class, "callWebservice");
```

And instead of storing to out in the route, then just use the move option so it becomes

```
from("file://C:/temp/camel/in?move=/temp/camel/out&moveFailed=/temp/camel/error")
  .bean(ServiceBean.class, "callWebservice");
```

Answer (score 0):

I don't think you can easily 'rollback' filesystem operations. Perhaps you could redesign your flow to first copy file to some intermediary 'stage' directory, do the work you need and depending on the outcome of that work move file to either 'output' or 'error' directory.